# Finding a solution to dA/dt=-5A if A(0)=5

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How does one find a particular solution to this problem? The question states:

Find a solution to $ \frac{dA}{dt} = -5A $ if A(0) = 5

Since they give the equivalence of $\frac{dA}{dt}$ A, integrating both sides gives me the following which isn't much help from what I can see. This is where I'm at and am stuck.

$$ A'(t) = -5A $$
$$ A(t) = \frac{-5}{2}A^2+C $$
$$ A(0) = 5 $$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Differentiate $ A(t) = \frac{-5}{2}(A(t))^2+C $ and compare with what you have above that equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integration step is not valid. The derivative $A'$ is taken with respect to the variable $t$, so

$\int A dt$ need not be $\frac {A^2}{2}$.

---

For a different technique, note that the equation is separable; treating $\frac{dA}{dt}$ as a fraction, we may rearrange the equation to find that

$$\frac{dA}{A} = -5 dt$$

Integrate both sides to obtain

$$\int \frac{dA}{A} = -5 \int dt \implies \ln{A} = -5t + c$$

Solve for $A$, then use the initial data to get $c$.

Comment: Why can we divide by $A$? :P

Comment: You can divide by A as long as A is not zero.

Comment: @Rasmus Using existence-uniqueness theorems, we find that a solution *must* exist, and by careful guess, we find that it's of the form $A(t) = ce^{-5t}$, which has no zero. But that's more of a solution by magic - it is, of course, recommended that the "solution" $A$ is verified to actually be a solution.

Comment: @imranfat The problem is that we don't know *a priori* that $A$ has no zeros.

Comment: True, to use seperation OF variables, we need to check at the end if A=0 is also a solution. I did not mention that, but when applying seperation of variables, that needs to be considered. And since the derivative of zero is -5 times 0, A=0 is a solution, but not needed for Bob's initial value problem

Comment: @imranfat You're mixing $(\forall t)(A(t)=0)$ and $(\exists t)(A(t)=0)$, hence T.Bonger's long comment above.

Comment: @T.Bongers How did you get $A(t)=ce^{-5t}$ I calculuated it to be $A(t)=e^{-5t+c}$. What am I missing?

Comment: @Bob $e^{-5t+c}=e^ce^{-5t}$. Now rename $e^c$ as $c$.

Comment: Yes, that's formally very correct, I just jumped onto seperation of variables because it would give Bob's answer to move on, without further details

Comment: @GitGud Why rename e^c to c? Isn't it true that e^c does not equal c?

Comment: @Bob You're correct. I will be a bit more formal. What you found was actually $(\exists c\in \Bbb R)(\forall t\in \Bbb R)(A(t)=e^{-5t+c})$, which in turn is equivalent to $(\exists c\in \Bbb R)(\forall t\in \Bbb R)(A(t)=\underbrace{e^c}_{=D}e^{-5t})$, which is equivalent to $(\exists D\in \Bbb R)(\forall t\in \Bbb R)(A(t)=De^{-5t})$ and since $D$ is a bounded variable you can replace it with any letter you like, for instance with $c$, yielding $(\exists c\in \Bbb R)(\forall t\in \Bbb R)(A(t)=ce^{-5t})$.

Comment: @Bob We're renaming an *arbitrary* constant as another *arbitrary* constant. It's an abuse of notation, but not a severe one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use seperation of variables. So divide by A and integrate both sides. You will get an e-power. The constant can be determined by using A(0)=5

Comment: Did you mean "separation **of** variables?"

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 1):

Remember that
if $f(t) = e^{ct}$,
then
$f'(t) = c e^{ct}
= c f(t)
$.

Since you want
$f'(t) = -5 f(t)$,
although you used
$A$ instead of $f$,
this corresponds to $c = -5$.

Therefore,
if $A(t)
= e^{-5t}$,
$A'(t) = (-5)e^{-5t}
= -5A(t)$.